# Jquery .click function with If Else Statement

Tags: jquery, function, if-statement, this

I am trying to create a click event that first displays a loading icon then a plus or minus icon. My code initially works on the first click but then when I click the same icon again it doesn't continue the if else statement.

Here is my Jquery code :

```
$('a.addQueue').click(function(){

    var plusIcon = '<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>';
    var minusIcon = '<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>';
    var loadingIcon = '<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i>';
    var innerIcon = $(this).html();

    $(this).html(loadingIcon).delay(500).queue(function(){
        if(innerIcon == plusIcon) {
            $(this).html(minusIcon);
        } else if (innerIcon == minusIcon) {
            $(this).html(plusIcon);
        }
    });

});
```

Here is my html code:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
<li>Item 1: <span class="semi-bold">xxxx</span> <a class="addQueue" href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
<li>Item 2: <span class="semi-bold">xxxx</span> <a class="addQueue" href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
<li>Item 3: <span class="semi-bold">xxxx</span> <a class="addQueue" href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
<li>Item 4: <span class="semi-bold">xxxx</span> <a class="addQueue" href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
<li>Item 5: <span class="semi-bold">xxxxx</span> <a class="addQueue" href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

What I want my function to do is when clicked on it should first call the load icon then the plus or minus icon depending on the inner html. Don't know what I am missing and I am fairly new to programming.

Here is my sample on js fidlle: http://jsfiddle.net/VZWV6/

Answer (score 4):

From the [`queue` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) you will find this:

> Note that when adding a function with jQuery.queue(), we should ensure
>   that jQuery.dequeue() is eventually called so that the next function
>   in line executes.

You are never dequeueing, so the next thing in line will never execute.  As a result, any animation effects (such as `delay`) or other `queue` calls will never execute as the original `queue` is never dequeued.

```
$(this).html(loadingIcon).delay(500).queue(function(){
    if(innerIcon == plusIcon) {
        $(this).html(minusIcon);
    } else if (innerIcon == minusIcon) {
        $(this).html(plusIcon);
    }

    $.dequeue(this);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VZWV6/7/

In any recent version of `jquery`, there is an even better alternative.  You can find this in the [`queue` documenation](http://api.jquery.com/queue/):

> As of jQuery 1.4, the function that's called is passed another
>   function as the first argument. When called, this automatically
>   dequeues the next item and keeps the queue moving.

This lets us do this instead:

```
$(this).html(loadingIcon).delay(500).queue(function(next){
    if(innerIcon == plusIcon) {
        $(this).html(minusIcon);
    } else if (innerIcon == minusIcon) {
        $(this).html(plusIcon);
    }

    next();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VZWV6/7/

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/Cq3Xs/)***

The callback function of **[queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)** expects that the function know how to dequeue itself. Since your function does not do that, the next time the queue function is pushed for that element, it is still waiting for the previous one to complete. In order to fix this, add `$( this ).dequeue();` to your queue function.

```
 $(this).html(loadingIcon).delay(500).queue(function(){
    if(innerIcon == plusIcon) {
        $(this).html(minusIcon);
    } else if (innerIcon == minusIcon) {
        $(this).html(plusIcon);
    }
    $( this ).dequeue();
 });
```